# 'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'Demystify' using Ben.Demystifier library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

I am trying to log exceptions in a better way where we can get human readable stack traces so I found out about this [Ben.Demystifier](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier) library and it looks promising.

I added this nuget dependency in my application.

```
<PackageReference Include="Ben.Demystifier" Version="0.1.6" />
```

Now in my catch block if I do like this then it gives me compilation error -

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Demystify());
}
```

Error I get -

```
> 'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'Demystify' and no
> accessible extension method 'Demystify' accepting a first argument of
> type 'Exception' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)
```

Anything wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in order to leverage the `Demystify` extension method, you need to do one of two things:

1. Ensure that the extension class `ExceptionExtentions` is available by adding a using directive.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
```

2. Call the extension method as a static method by fully qualifying the namespace.

```cs
System.Diagnostics.ExceptionExtentions.Demystify(ex);
```

Comment: Aftert adding the namespace now I dont see compilation error. Thanks for your response. I also updated my question with the detail of what we are running so just wanted to make sure it is still good idea to use `Ben.Demystifier` library to get stacktrace in better way compared to using traditional `ex.Stacktrace` way?

Comment: You can get the (potentially null) stack trace of an exception by accessing `Exception.StackTrace`. It looks like `Ben.Demystifier` takes the stack trace information, and presents it in a more readable manner based on a variety of language techniques (iterators, generics, async, etc.).

Comment: yeah I know that I can use `Exception.StackTrace` to print out the stacktrace info but I was thinking if it is best to use `Ben.Demystifier` to print out the exceptions instead of using traditional way?

Comment: I think it can be an opinionated topic. I have not used the library in any of my projects, but based on nuget.org's stats it looks like it is a pretty popular addition. My recommendation is to use your judgement, compare the standard stack traces to the overhead (file size, licensing, company policy, runtime performance) of including an additional library.